# Sencha Touch Custom field

Tags: sencha-touch-2.2

I have this custom field in my form. But when i do the form.getValues() the values for this field is empty. Is this the right way to create custom form fields.

```
Ext.define("Tasks.view.BarcodeField", {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    alias:'widget.barcodeField',

    xtype: 'barcodefield',

    config: {    
        layout: 'hbox',
        id: 'barcodeField',
        itemId: 'barcodeField',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                label: 'Barcode',
                labelWidth: '37.4%',                            
                flex: 4        
            },
            {
                xtype: 'image',
                id : 'barcodeScanner',
                itemId : 'barcodeScanner',
                src: 'resources/images/barcodes.png',
                padding: '6 0 0 0',
                flex: 1,
                listeners: {
                    tap: function() {
                        console.log("Starting the barcode Scanner");
                        function success(result) {
                             alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                            "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                            "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                            "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
                        }

                        function fail(error) {
                              alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
                        }

                         cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(success, fail);
                    }
                }               
            }        
        ]        
    },

    getValue : function() 
    {   
        console.log(this.getItems().getAt(0).getValue());
        return this.getItems().getAt(0).getValue();
    },
    setValue : function(newvalue) {
       this.getItems().getAt(0).setValue(newvalue);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of extending from the Container i extended the Ext.field.Field and added the items as children to that component.

```
Ext.define("Tasks.view.BarcodeField", {
extend: 'Ext.field.Field',
alias:'widget.barcodeField',

xtype: 'barcodefield',

config: {    
    layout: 'hbox',
    id: 'barcodeField',
    itemId: 'barcodeField',
    isField:false,
    component : {
        xtype:'panel',
        layout:'hbox',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'input',
                label: 'Barcode',
                labelWidth: '37.4%',                            
                flex: 4,
                id:'barcodeTextField',
                itemId:'barcodeTextField'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'image',
                id : 'barcodeScanner',
                itemId : 'barcodeScanner',
                src: 'resources/images/barcodes.png',
                padding: '6 0 0 0',
                flex: 1,
                listeners: {
                    tap: function() {
                        console.log("Starting the barcode Scanner");
                        var text = Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#barcodeTextField")[0];
                            text.setValue("123456");

                    }
                }               
            }        
        ]   
    }       
},

getValue : function() 
{   
    console.log(this.getComponent().getItems().getAt(0).getValue());
    return this.getComponent().getItems().getAt(0).getValue();
},
setValue : function(newvalue) {
   this.getComponent().getItems().getAt(0).setValue(newvalue);
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add a formpanel as the first child wich will contain a textfield inside in.

And afterward do the formpanel.getValues() to get the values from every field inside that formpanel.

and the other thing is you can do

```
this.getItems()[0].getValue();
this.getItems()[0].setValue('someDesiredValue');
```

but that being said I will really prefer doing that on the controller class.